# Install libdnet Python wrapper for ScaPy

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python3, scapy

How to install the Python (3) wrapper for [libdnet](https://github.com/boundary/libdnet) on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS?  I need is as  it is a  [pre-requisite to  ScaPy](https://phaethon.github.io/scapy/api/installation.html), however the [Python 3.x wrapper does not seem to exist yet](http://libdnet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: For Python 2, you could install `python-dumbnet`. Is that okay or does it have to be Python 3?

Comment: The site you linked says "*Scapy can run natively on Linux. I does not require libdnet and libpcap.*" - So you only need this libdnet wrapper on non-Linux systems.

Comment: Indeed. You are right. Thank you very much for the precious comment. I did not see that before. @ByteCommander

Comment: @ByteCommander:  Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Fabby Done as you wished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you only need `libdnet` to use ScaPy.

But this is a false assumption. ScaPy only requires this library (or wrappers for it) when you are **not on a Linux system**.

You can read that on [their site's installation page](https://phaethon.github.io/scapy/api/installation.html):

- > (For non-Linux platforms): Install libpcap and libdnet and their Python wrappers.
- > Scapy can run natively on Linux. I does not require libdnet and libpcap.

So unless you come up with another use case, there's no need for a Python 3 wrapper to `libdnet`.